# Pexpect Methods Not Working

Tags: python, pexpect

I am running CentOS7 and have installed pexpect in Python3.5. However, when I call any of the methods it is returning an error stating the attribute does not exist.  Any ideas why this is occurring? I read that it could be due to a file name pexpect.py in the directory but I do NOT have a file called pexpect.py in the same directory.

```
$ pip3.5 freeze | grep pexpect
pexpect==4.2.1
```

Example Code:

```
# This connects to the openbsd ftp site and
# downloads the recursive directory listing.
import pexpect
child = pexpect.spawn('ftp ftp.openbsd.org')
child.expect('Name .*: ')
child.sendline('anonymous')
child.expect('Password:')
child.sendline('noah@example.com')
child.expect('ftp> ')
child.sendline('lcd /tmp')
child.expect('ftp> ')
child.sendline('cd pub/OpenBSD')
child.expect('ftp> ')
child.sendline('get README')
child.expect('ftp> ')
child.sendline('bye')
```

Error:

CentOS7 Virtual Machine Error:

```
/usr/local/bin/python3.5 /media/sf_PycharmProjects/MyPyScripts/Tutorials/input_cmds
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/media/sf_PycharmProjects/MyPyScripts/Tutorials/input_cmds", line 4, in <module>
    child = pexpect.spawn('ftp ftp.openbsd.org')
AttributeError: module 'pexpect' has no attribute 'spawn'
```

Windows Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/home/PycharmProjects/PyCAT/Current_Version/SFTP/testsftp.py", line 4, in <module>
    child = pexpect.spawn('ftp ftp.openbsd.org')
AttributeError: module 'pexpect' has no attribute 'spawn'
```

Pexpect Dir:

```
>>> import pexpect
>>> dir(pexpect)
['__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__']
```

Comment: Can you add the full traceback to your post?

Comment: @Morgan Thrapp Hi, I've added the full Traceback.

Comment: I can reproduce this on Windows. There may be an issue with the module itself, or at least the docs.

Comment: @Morgan Thrapp, I also added the output that I get on a CentOS7 virtual machine in windows. It is pretty much the same.

Comment: Yeah, I would suggest you file a bug with the project maintainers. Someone may have a workaround (I've never used pexpect), but this is definitely a bug in their docs if nothing else.

Comment: Thanks for the input.

Comment: 1. Also check for any `pexpect.pyc` files

2. Try `dir(pexpect)` after importing to see if there are any hints as to what you actually loaded

Comment: @mattbornski I dont see any pexpect.pyc files.  I posted the dir(pexpect) above. Is there something specific I should look for?

Comment: @MBasith what's really interesting there is that it doesn't seem to expose any of the normal pexpect functions.  I'm using Python 2.7 so not quite the same, but for instance my `dir(pexpect)` is `dir(pexpect)
['EOF', 'ExceptionPexpect', 'Expecter', 'PY3', 'TIMEOUT', '__all__', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__revision__', '__version__', 'exceptions', 'expect', 'is_executable_file', 'pty_spawn', 'run', 'runu', 'searcher_re', 'searcher_string', 'spawn', 'spawnbase', 'spawnu', 'split_command_line', 'sys', 'utils', 'which']`

Comment: @MBasith do me a favor, instead of `import pexpect` try `from pexpect import pexpect`.  Just spitballing but that's another common module structure in my experience.

Comment: @mattbornski Thanks for the follow up I also tried that but same result. I may just install a new Linux VM and try re-installing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, for the Windows Error I can tell you that Pexpect.spawn doesn't work on windows. This has to do something with pypi that provides some modules only on linux systems, and `spawn` uses one of those parts.

On Windows you have to use PopenSpawn instead.